# Prove inequality using AM-GM

Tags: inequality, contest-math, arithmetic

How can you prove
$a^2-ab+b^2 \geq ab$ using AM-GM?

Comment: hint: $a^2-2ab+b^2=(a-b)^2\geq 0$

Comment: Square both sides of the AM-GM inequality, write out the square $((a+b)/2)^2$ and then rearrange the terms.

Answer (score 1):

$a^2−2ab+b^2=(a−b)^2\geq 0 \implies a^2-ab+b^2 \geq ab$